# Flatten a dictionary to an argument list of its elements

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, parameter-passing, flatten

In Python when a function takes a various number of parameters of the same type and when these parameters are given as elements in a dictionary, how can I "flatten" the dictionary to a parameter list?

Take as an example the function `bartlett` in `scipy.stats`. It takes an arbitrary number of np-array and compares their variances. Its definition starts:

```
def bartlett(*args):
    ...
```

The np-arrays I want to compare are stored in a dictionary(*):

```
data = { 'gender': gender-array, 'lefthome': lefthome-array, ... }
```

How can I write the list of parameters using *all* elements in the dictionary without explicitly listing them via the key-access. So I'm looking for something like:

```
barlett(data[*])
```

---

(*) The np-arrays are extracted from a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: enumerate the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: what do you mean under _all_ _elements_? if you want pass dictionary values just call barlett(*data.values())

Comment: @vitalii Well what works is explicitly listing the elements: `bartlett{data['gender'], data['lefthome'],...)` but that is cumbersome.

Comment: @halloleo ok so try `bartlett(*data.values())`

Comment: @vitalii yes, but for *all* elements in the dictionary (there might be more than these two).

Comment: @vitalii Aaah, yes that's it. Cool! So the `*` does the 'flattening".

Comment: @halloleo for future: you can also pass dict as keyword arguments just calling `function(**data)`, and e.g. if `data={'a': 1, 'b': 2}` this call is same as calling `function(a=1, b=2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106134/discussion-between-vitalii-and-halloleo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call

```
bartlett(*data.values())
```